# Fatal errors when building Knockout.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, knockout.js, gruntjs, npm

Running a *totally fresh* instance of Ubuntu 13.10 x64 on DigitalOcean. Every time I try and build Knockout.js using npm/grunt I get the following error:

```
Running "clean" task

Running "checktrailingspaces:main" (checktrailingspaces) task

Running "build:debug" (build) task

Running "build:min" (build) task
Compiling...Fatal error: spawn ENOENT
```

The strange part is, the Fatal error is seemingly random. It is always one of these three:

```
Fatal error: spawn ENOENT
Fatal error: spawn EPIPE
Fatal error: spawn ECONNRESET
```

I can build everything successfully on Mac OS X as well as an instance of Ubuntu 13.10 x64 at Linode, as well as Ubuntu 13.10 x64 on my home machine. I spun up several instances of Ubuntu 13.10 on different hosts and could only reproduce it on DigitalOcean.

I'm thinking something is funky with DigitalOcean's Ubuntu images, but do not know enough to say for sure. I could be missing some prerequisite packages, but I read all the docs and made sure I met all the requirements for Node/npm/grunt.

I have contacted DigitalOcean and got some *great* support. An employee managed to reproduce my errors but did not find a solution.

Any help is appreciated greatly.

**Edit:** My issue was solved below, and had *absolutely nothing* to do with DigitalOcean's images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fatal error: spawn ENOENT` means [child_process.spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) in node.js cannot find the binary you're attempting to spawn.

So likely you have some dependency the library requires installed on your OSX machine but not on the Ubuntu machine.

Look into your `build` task to see where and what it is trying to spawn. Running grunt with `grunt --stack` should help.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your suggestion led me to realize that I didn't have Clojure installed on my machine. After installing I managed to successfully build Knockout. I still got an error in my output `Fatal error: Object true has no method 'replace'` but at least the build process successfully completed. I should be able to debug this last issue.

Comment: Good catch. I forgot to install graphicsmagick when attempting to run my app. That error is undebuggable. I will add a non node dependency check to my app start now!